# How would you write this map-filter chain using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

The following `map`-`filter` chain takes a list of numbers and doubles them, filters the results using some predicate `p`, then squares those that remain:

```
getNumbers().map(x => x * 2).filter(x => p(x)).map(x => x ** 2)
```

The idiomatic Python equivalent requires nested list comprehensions:

```
[y ** 2 for y in [x * 2 for x in getNumbers()] if p(y)]
```

How would you write this in C# using LINQ? Does it also require nesting?

Answer (score 4):

You could use the LINQ select function in place of map and Where in place of filter

```
getNumbers().Select(x => x * 2).Where(x => p(x)).Select(x => Math.Pow(x, 2)).ToList();
```

An alternative way to do this using LINQ is with query syntax.

```
from x in getNumbers()
    select x * 2 into x
    where x > p(x)
    select Math.Pow(x, 2)
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. It seems people generally prefer this method syntax, but is it possible to do this using query syntax?

Comment: I think method syntax works better here because of the double select. I believe the equivalent in query syntax would look like: "FROM x IN getNumbers() WHERE (x * 2) > p(x) SELECT Math.Pow((x * 2), 2)". In this you need to perform the multiplication twice which adds some extra cycles. I'm by no means an expert in query syntax so if someone can show how it is a better solution in this instance it would be great to learn!

Comment: I was wrong! After some playing around there is an equivalent version in query syntax. Updated the answer with an example

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you would write it in LINQ like this:

```
var myNumbers = GetNumbers().Select(x => x * 2).Where(y => p(y)).Select(z => Math.Pow(z, 2)).ToList();
```

Comment: I guess there should be square of z in the last Select, not multiplication by 2.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. It seems people generally prefer this method syntax, but is it possible to do this using query syntax?

Comment: @user200783 See Sam's answer above for LINQ query syntax.  I find the query syntax to be too verbose.  I use it only if the method syntax can't accomplish what I want which is rare.